# Is $H_0^1([a,b]) \subset C([a,b],\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

i have a small question : how to see that $H_0^1([a,b])\subset C([a,b],\mathbb{R})$?

Please

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Hint: for any $[x,y] \subseteq [a,b]$

$$ f(y) - f(x) = \int_x^y f'(s) \mathrm{d}s  \leq \int_x^y |f'(s)| \mathrm{d}s \leq \|f'\|_{L^2([x,y])} \|1\|_{L^2([x,y])} $$

so $f$ is in fact uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by $H^1_0$ being a subset of continuous 
functions but I am guessing what you need is the Sobolev embedding 
theorem (see [Adams and Fournier](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Sobolev_Spaces.html?id=R5A65Koh-EoC&redir_esc=y) or [McLean](http://books.google.ca/books?id=RILqjEeMfK0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=mclean+strongly+elliptic&hl=en&sa=X&ei=f6cKUv9-iPGJAvrMgbgE&ved=0CEIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=mclean%20strongly%20elliptic&f=false)) which essentially
states the following:

Suppose $0< \mu <1$. If $u \in H^{n/2+ \mu}(R^n) $, then $u$ is almost 
everywhere equal to a Holder-continuous function. Embedding of $H^1_0$ 
in one dimension follows from this result immediately.

Comment: i want to prove that $H_0^1 \hookrightarrow C([a,b],\mathbb{R})$, can i prove the contnuity of the injection and the injection in the same time ? please thank you

Comment: there are various ways of proving the theorem. I am not sure if you can prove both at the same time, if you look at the proof on page 86 of McLean he starts by bounding the absolute value by the sobolev norm and then shows holder continuity which is a bit more involved. The argument provided by @Willie above will help you with the last step where you want to show the holder continuity but first you need to show continuity.